# nginx how to forward a port proxy a port

Tags: nginx

I want to be able to visit `https://localhost:888/` in my browser and have it behave identically as if I had accessed `https://localhost:999/`

How can I do that?

I tried adding

```
server {
    listen   888;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:999;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

to a new file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/default`, but I can't access any webpage at `localhost:888` (even though localhost:999 responds fine)

I am using homebrew (`brew install nginx`) version of nginx

Comment: What is the Error you are seeing when you try to access `http://localhost:888/` in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 there is just no server listening there. can't open the page because Safari can't connect to the server. Same as visiting http://expendanasishaga.com